# allow vs. allow for

Tags: grammar

Could anybody tell me which of the following is correct?

(1) *This app **allows** up to 100 actions per day.*

(2) *This app **allows for** up to 100 actions per day.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Allows for up to** for means "facilitates" or "is instrumental in providing," whereas **allows up to** without **for** means "exercises authority and restricts to no more than."

Use "allow" if you wish to communicate that your app is limiting people from performing more than 100 actions a day (like, because you are trying to get them to pay to do more, or you have some reason for *dis*allowing more than 100/day).

Use "allow for" if you are stating that for some non-intentional reason, your app may not be suitable for those who need to make more than 100 actions per day.

Comment: 'Allow for' usually means 'be designed to cope with'.

Answer (score 1):

They have slightly different connotations but generally mean the same thing.

"Allows" simply means a general meaning of allowance of something. "Allows for" generally means allowing a particular event or action that may happen in the future. Both are correct here. The second one is slightly more specific, however.

I can think of two examples that would best fit the connotations of these word forms:

> Users can earn coins in-app. The app allows up to 1,000 coins to be stored in the virtual wallet.
>
> Users can earn coins in-app. The app allows for the accumulation of up to 1,000 coins.

To allow for is to make an allowance for something. In your second example, your app is making an allowance for up to 100 actions to be performed per day. In the first, it is simply permitting this number of actions per day.

Honestly, it's hard to know which example I'd choose without the context. It depends how much you want to emphasise the actions as an action (the action part of it) or as a unit (the value it contributes to the total).

Edit: I would probably go with "allows".